# ASP.Net - MVC 5 - log user off if user left a particular area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, header, identity

The goal:
I am trying to get the user to log off if they leave this area.
Area name: employer
if the user goes to the home page or anywhere else on the web and tries to log in or hits the back button I want the system to end the users session.

for example:
**www.example.com/employer/dashboard** - is protected and the user has to be logged in to access this area.

if the user goes to www.google.com and try to go back to **www.example.com/employer/dashboard** their session ends and they are redirected to the login page.

Some Questions:

- Would it be a good idea to make an extend to the AuthorizeAttribute?
- How would I log the user off?
- How can I detect if the user leaves the area and comes back.
- Should I make some sort of base controller that all of the other controllers inherit in the area so the area is protected?
- Should the solution be server side?

any advice would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such purposes ASP.NET MVC authorization filters are used, which runs before any other filter.

the idea is to check if Path matches with Safe path then load area, otherwise don't authenticate and redirect to login. The tricky part is to control flow and not be trapped in page loop.

Check out this:
 http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=957

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onunload) event and logout your user when this event occurs.

Comment: I am guessing that it won't if the user modifies the html or disables javascript.

Comment: You can use SignalR to track user in real time. Just track connection close event to logout user.